# Using Max in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to run a query that returns the maximum number in the ballNumber field when the value in the inningsNo field is 1. I just can't get it to work. Can anyone tell me what I should enter into the Criteria box?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: hmmm.. why is this question closed? I do not think it is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob,

To do this, you will need to do the following:

1. Click on the "Totals" button on the Query ribbon (a new row will appear in the Query grid labelled "Total");
2. Change the "Group By" Total value to "Where" in the InningsNo column (the tick in the "Show" will also disappear);
3. Change the "Group By" Total value to "Max" in the ballNumber column.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Applecore